# Unkown polynomial function

Tags: functions

Let $F(x)$ be a polynomial function of degree $2018$ and leading coefficient unity such that $F(0) = 2017$, $F(1) = 2016$, $F(2) = 2015, \ldots$, $F(2017) = 0$. The value of $F(2018)$ is of the form $n! - a$. where $n, a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a$ is least possible value, then $n + a$ is equal to what?

I am not getting any start .

Comment: $n+a$ is equal to what?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011961/if-p-is-a-monic-polynomial-of-degree-2015-such-that-pi-2014-i-quad-forall/2011971#2011971

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the polynomial function $g(x)=x+f(x)-2017$.

The degree of $g$ is $2018$. Based on the information given, $0,1,2, \ldots , 2017$ are all roots of $g$.

Thus 
$$g(x)=x(x-1)(x-2) \dotsb (x-2017)$$

Can you take it from here?